# Relative paths in init file

Tags: init-file

When loading things like themes from custom directories, is it possible to specify a path relative to the init.el file, rather than an absolute path?

I ask because I want to be able to use the same config file across my OSX and Windows machines, where an absolute path like ~/.emacs.d/themes means something different on each machine (I'm not even sure how Windows handles ~)

Comment: MS Windows handles `~/` the same way: as your home directory, the value of environment variable `HOME`.

Comment: @Drew I just tried to `cd ~/` in cmd but the path could not be found, despite having the HOME variable correctly set...

Comment: Normally, `cd` is enough for going to your home directory. Also, you're better use powershell, cmd is definitely out-dated.

Comment: Did you start with `emacs -Q`? Did you define environment variable `HOME`? Did you do `M-x cd RET ~/ RET`? Works for me.

Comment: The Windows cmd.exe shell does not understand ~, but Emacs on Windows will handle it. @Nsukami_: cd (at a cmd prompt) will print the current directory, not change to your home dir.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use ~/ in your init file and it will work fine on Windows. I always define a HOME environment variable and put my .emacs.d there, but there are other approaches. See [the FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq-w32.html#Location-of-init-file) for the details of how Emacs decides what to use for home.

You can also build paths with the `user-emacs-directory` variable, if you prefer:

```
 (expand-file-name "foo.el" user-emacs-directory)
```

which in my case would be interchangeable with just `"~/.emacs.d/foo.el"`.

.

Comment: If memory serves, you can also use MS Windows environment variables in file name (they will be expanded), however you'd need to use UNIX syntax (i.e. `$PROGRAMFILES` instead of `%PROGRAMFILES%`, but I cannot check it at the moment).

Comment: You can also use locate-user-init-file instead.

Answer (score 0):

[load-relative](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/load-relative.html) was written to do something like this. Its purpose those was to do relative linking within a package, but I believe it can be used here as well.